# Body window scrolling area with native scrollbar

Tags: css, window, scrollbar

I have an CSS overflow issue which seems not be an issue but I can't see the solution.

Here we go:
I want the body to be scrollable within a window so it has a frame and the window should be scrollable even the mouse is over that frame and the scrollbar should has the native position of it. At the moment in my solution the scrollbar is beside the window inside the frame but it should be outside the frame where it is generally.

//Edit I want the window to be fixed in that area it is in my example. So the window doesn't scroll but the content is scrollable.

I thought I just can reach that by giving the body a margin but it won't work that way.

It should look like this:
[image]

Thanks for helping.

Take a look at my code here:
https://codepen.io/knorke/pen/bGMBgqO

HTML:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
p {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
html {
    background: red;    
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 40px;
    margin:100px 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 

<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom:40px;
}
p {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
html {
    background: red;    
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
body {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    padding: 40px;
    margin:100px 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p> 

<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.</p>
```

Comment: I see I was not precise enough. I want the window to be fixed in that area it is in my example. so the window doesn't scroll but the content is scrollable.